# Create "dropdown" comment box within a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, popup, drop-down-menu

I'm very new to ASP.NET and imagine this is possible, but I have a grid view with a handful of columns. One of the columns has a button, that when clicked, I'd like a box to appear below the button (to ensure its visibility) that allows the user to add comments, submit comments, and cancel. I'm not too worried about the last three pieces of functionality yet, but am stuck on just getting the comments box to pop up in the right spot.

My idea functionality would be to have the rows below the clicked button the shift down to leave a space for the comments box, and once it is submitted, to have it disappear and the other rows back in place. The second best solution would be to have a pop-up window.

I must also note that I am on a closed system that cannot have any plugins installed, though it does have jquery.

I can elaborate on my problem if needed.

Comment: So you need to create a click handler for the button and within that callback method you set the visibility of the comments box to true (and any other controls you need to make the comments work). Additionally you can access any attributes of the grid view to change css styling, such as hiding rows. Need to see some code to be able to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

you can use either Accordion, HoverMenu or ModalPopup. please go to the following link for the demo and select your choice.

[AjaxControlToolkit Demo](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but I'm on a closed system that I cannot install anything without a long and arduous approval cycle.